# phpRunner insert statement CURDATE not working

Tags: date, insert

I'm currently using phpRunner but account expired. So have to post the question here instead of the phpRunner forum.

What i need is to insert CURDATE into database with the following code:

```
$sql3 = "insert into bed_remarks (unit_id,bed_id,bed_remarks) values ('".$datatmp["unit_id"]."','".$datatmp["bed_id"]."','Previously housed ".$datatmp["employee_num"].' '.$datatmp["worker_name"]." CONCAT(Check out on ,CURDATE())')";
CustomQuery($sql3);
```

However, the result return was as such:
"1, 1, Previously housed 00000002 Test Worker 2 CONCAT(Check out on ,CURDATE())"

Instead of inserting (The result I want):
"1, 1, Previously housed 00000002 Test Worker 2 Check out on 2013-08-07"

I tried adding ' or ". in front and after the statement, but it does work.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use DATE() instead of CURDATE()

Answer (score 0):

in PHPRunner, you can use `now();`